# videojs player + google IMA ads - how to subscribe for an event

Tags: javascript, video.js, google-ima

I'm trying to run some test code using `video.js` player with google [IMA plugin](https://github.com/googleads/videojs-ima)

I used a simple example provided by the plugin's authors:
https://github.com/googleads/videojs-ima/tree/master/examples/simple

And now I try to subscribe for some of the ads-player events.

I tried to subscribe for the events in following way (changes in lines 48+ of the original sample code):

```
player.one(startEvent, function() {

    player.ima.onAdStarted_ = function(){
        console.log("Ad started");
    }

    player.ima.onAdPlayPauseClick_ = function(){
        console.log("Ad clicked");
    }

    player.ima.onAdComplete_ = function(){
        console.log("Ad completed");
    }

    player.ima.initializeAdDisplayContainer();
    player.ima.requestAds();
    player.play();
});
```

And it captures the events correctly, but the main player is broke: after the ad is finished the IMA controls are not being disabled (they overlay the controls of the main player) and we have no control over the video.

I assume I accidently overrided some of the IMA's events and it's not working properly.

I also tried to add event listeners like that:

```
player.one(startEvent, function() { 


    player.ima.initializeAdDisplayContainer();
    player.ima.addEventListener("click",function(){
        console.log("Ad clicked");
    });

    player.ima.addEventListener(google.ima.AdEvent.Type.STARTED,function(){
        console.log("Ad started");
    });

    player.ima.addEventListener(google.ima.AdEvent.Type.ALL_ADS_COMPLETED, function(){
        console.log("Ad completed");
    });
    player.ima.requestAds();
    player.play();
});
```

But it's not working.

Is there a **proper** way to subscribe for the IMA's events, mainly for "ad started", "ad clicked" and "ad ended" events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I managed to solve my problem.

The trick is to rewrite the plugin located in `videojs-ima.js` file and there one has access to all needed events of `adsManager` and `adsLoader` objects.

I.e. (code added at line 208):

```
adsManager.addEventListener(
    google.ima.AdEvent.Type.STARTED,
    function(){
         console.log("Ad started");
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

`TLDR;`

```
player.on("adsready", function(){
  player.ima.addEventListener(google.ima.AdEvent.Type.CLICK, function(){
    console.log(">>> ad clicked");
  });
});
```

---

This solution is undocumented, your code doesn't work because when you add the event listener, `adsManager` hasn't been created. Take a look at the following snippet from googleads/videojs-ima repository.

```
// https://github.com/googleads/videojs-ima/blob/master/src/videojs.ima.js#L758-L769
player.ima.addEventListener = function(event, callback) {
  if (adsManager) {
    adsManager.addEventListener(event, callback);
  }
};
```

To be able to add event listener on ads manager, one have to listen to `adsready` event, because it is emitted at the end of ads manager creation, look at the following snippet.

```
// https://github.com/googleads/videojs-ima/blob/master/src/videojs.ima.js#L219-L278
player.ima.onAdsManagerLoaded_ = function(adsManagerLoadedEvent) {
  adsManager = adsManagerLoadedEvent.getAdsManager(
      contentPlayheadTracker, adsRenderingSettings);

  // other code
  // ...

  player.trigger('adsready');
};
```

Therefore to listen to google ima ad events, you must add the event listener **after** `adsready` event emitted as follows.

```
player.on("adsready", function(){
  player.ima.addEventListener(google.ima.AdEvent.Type.CLICK, function(){
    console.log(">>> ad clicked");
  });
});
```